# In this code, how can I get a list of fields that were created and modified by today?

Tags: apex, metadata, fields

```
public class demo {
    public static void getSOjectsWithFields(){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Set<String> standardObjects = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> customObjects = new Set<String>();
        List<String> allObj = new List<String>();
        for(Schema.SObjectType d : gd.values()) {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ds = d.getDescribe();
            if(!ds.isCreateable()) {
                continue;
            }
            if(ds.isCustom() == false && ds.getRecordTypeInfos().size() > 0) {
                allObj.add(ds.getName());
            } else if(ds.isCustom()) {
                allObj.add(ds.getName());
            }
            //system.debug('allObj---'+allObj);
        }
        Map<Schema.SObjectType,Map<String, Schema.sObjectField>> ObjectswithFields=  new Map<Schema.SObjectType,Map<String, Schema.sObjectField>>();
        for(string allobjects: allObj ){
            //system.debug('allobjects---'+allobjects);
            Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(allobjects);
            Map<String, Schema.sObjectField> targetFields = targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            //system.debug('targetFields---'+targetFields);
            ObjectswithFields.put(targetType,targetFields);
        }
        system.debug('ObjectswithFields-----'+ ObjectswithFields);
        for(Schema.SObjectType obj: ObjectswithFields.keyset()){
            //system.debug('obj---'+obj);
            Map<String, Schema.sObjectField> fieldList = ObjectswithFields.get(obj);
            //system.debug('fieldList---'+fieldList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get that information with normal describe calls. You'd have to call a query from the [Tooling API CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm).

Comment: Sample query: select id, TableEnumOrId, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix, lastmodifiedby.name, lastmodifieddate  from customfield where lastmodifieddate >= yesterday